# Nginx: location regex not working

Tags: nginx, regex, proxypass

i'm getting trouble with my regex don't know what is wrong with  it. it's returning a URi with `orls/f` instead of `orls/f?p=4550`. When i pass `https://secure.toto02.com/orls/myservice/f?p=4550`

my conf file is below

```
 location ~ "^/([a-zA-Z]+)/myservice/(.+)$" {

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-server.log notice;
    rewrite_log on;  

    #proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    proxy_pass http://192.168.3.45:8080/orls/$2;    
    proxy_redirect http://192.168.3.45:8080/orls/ https://secure.toto02.com/$1/myservice/ ;          
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing the location will not encompass the query string. You have to manually include it via `$is_args` and `$args` variables like so:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.3.45:8080/orls/$2$is_args$args;
```

See @kolbyjack's (much better) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/with-nginx-how-to-forward-query-parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot been on it for a while. Was a bout to go crazy on this one .